# add a column to an existing table using a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the bad title, and the probably silly question. I am pretty new to SQL

I have a table 'df' with a column named code. I have a different table 'dictionary' with two columns, code and description.
I want to add the column description to table A based on . My attempt so far

```
alter table df add description datatype

update df
set A.description = B.description
from  df A inner join dictionary B on A.code = B.code
```

I am getting a couple of issues with this code, and I am not quite sure why.Is there a better way? Am i missusing the aliases?

Comment: As a side comment, adding a code description to a base table is not recommended for most databases and it is not following normal form (NF). You should create a view instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error in the update. If you use alias, you will have to use it after the update command

```
update A
set description = B.description
from  df A inner join dictionary B on A.code = B.code
```

Comment: Confirmed.  Added SQL Fiddle as an example.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e9ae/2

Comment: Thanks @TinyHaitian, I need to be less lazy and more like you and fiddle my answers when doable

Comment: Not a problem.   I just like adding them to prove a point, and if they have an issue, they can test it within the given environment.